# Does simulating color space on Android 5.0 use more power than disabling it

Tags: android

I was wondering if simulating monochromacy color space would use more power than it being disabled. (On an AMOLED screen.)

Simulating color space is in developer settings on Android 5.0.

Thanks

Comment: Does this question have to do with a program/app you wrote? or is this just something you wanted to find out from a user perspective because you were curious?

Comment: @CaptJak it has to do with an app i wrote. Specifically on an AMOLED screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any conclusive source for this answer, but if you think about it, then yes, simulating a monochrome color space on an AMOLED screen should save battery life, as long as the entire screen isn't lit all the time (then it wouldn't make a difference).

AMOLED screens don't use any light to display black pixels, they're just off. So if you simulate monochrome, you will end up with more blacks (usually instead of colors with a dark value will show as black, so those pixels will be off instead of a dark red [for example]).

Comment: I don't think it's that easy. When you had only a red pixel before, you end up with all 3 RGB sub-pixels turned on (at a lower rate then the single red one). And if you look at http://blackandwhitedigital.com/images/gif/converted/combined.jpg top right, depending on conversion algorithm, monochrome can require quite the bright light grey to represent colors. Also you need to factor in that calculations for monochrome conversion cost extra energy. (edit: image is terrible example because it's just rgb channels separated but monochrome mostly distributes the energy one color had over all 3)

Comment: @zapl yea i tried to test this out on a Samsung GS5. I used Trepn profiler to measure avg. GPU Load. When i enabled Samsung's own power saving greyscale mode it had a really low avg. GPU load. But when i tested  simulating monochromacy, the avg. GPU load was significantly higher. Im assuming higher GPU load equals to higher power consumption.  Any ideas on how Sasmung might be achieving this.  Thanks.

Comment: @nik no idea. Maybe shaders but more likely directly at a lower level. The big advantage they have is that they can implement that in an efficient way & place, like in the gpu or display driver which has color calibration facilities anyways.

Comment: @zapl, how did the testing go? Does the battery last longer or does it drain faster with the higher GPU? I'm interested to know what data your tests turn out.